# MySQL: How to add one day to datetime field in query

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table I have a field named `eventdate` in `datetime` format like `2010-05-11 00:00:00`.

How do i make a query so that it adds **one day** to the `eventdate` eg if today is `2010-05-11`, i want to show in `where` clause to return all records with tomorrow's date.

**Update:**

I tried this:

`select * from fab_scheduler where custid = 1334666058 and DATE_ADD(eventdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

But unfortunately it returns the same record even if i add an interval greater than 1.

**Result:**

`2010-05-12 00:00:00`

But i only want to select records with tomorrow's date.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can use the [`DATE_ADD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function:

```
... WHERE DATE(DATE_ADD(eventdate, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) = CURRENT_DATE
```

It can also be used in the `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2010-05-11', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS Tomorrow;
+------------+
| Tomorrow   |
+------------+
| 2010-05-12 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @phpBOY: I think you missed the ` = CURRENT_DATE` part.

Comment: i tried this `select * from fab_scheduler where custid = 1334666058 and DATE(DATE_ADD(eventdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) = CURRENT_DATE
` but now it returns empty result set :(

Comment: I would use CURDATE() personally

Comment: @phpBOY: You're right. You have to use `-1` to match with `CURRENT_DATE`. Try with the updated query.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo: Could you please construct the query, iam getting empty record set. Thanks

Comment: @phpBOY: Did you try: `select * from fab_scheduler where custid = 1334666058 and DATE(DATE_ADD(eventdate, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) = CURRENT_DATE`

Comment: @David: Any reason why you prefer `CURDATE()`?... `CURDATE()` and `CURRENT_DATE` are synonyms according to [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date).

Answer (score 8):

Have a go with this, as this is how I would do it :)

```
SELECT * 
FROM fab_scheduler
WHERE custid = '123456'
AND CURDATE() = DATE(DATE_ADD(eventdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Comment: I don't think that can work. `eventdate` will never be equal to `eventdate + 1 day`. I think you intended to use `CURDATE()` in there.

Answer (score 8):

It`s possible to use MySQL specific syntax sugar:

```
SELECT ... date_field + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Looks much more pretty instead of DATE_ADD function

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use NOW() this would be simplest form:

```
SELECT * FROM `fab_scheduler` WHERE eventdate>=(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND eventdate<NOW() ORDER BY eventdate DESC;
```

With MySQL 5.6+ query abowe should do. Depending on sql server, You may be required to use `CURRDATE()` instead of `NOW()` - which is alias for `DATE(NOW())` and will return only date part of `datetime` data type;

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD(m_inv_reqdate, INTERVAL + 1 DAY)) FROM  tr08_investment
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select * from fab_scheduler where custid = 1334666058 and eventdate = eventdate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 day");
```

Or, simplier:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()+((60*60)*24));
```

Comment: You didn't count on daylight savings time. mktime would be better.