# Select continues dates from table

Tags: php, mysql

This is little confusing me how to select dates from table on continuous basis.
Suppose i have absent_report table and have entries like this,

```
Sno Code    date
1   101 01-01-2014
2   101 02-01-2014
3   101 03-01-2014

4   101 05-01-2014
5   101 06-01-2014
6   101 07-01-2014
```

I only want to select continues date from a date. like first three dates not fourth one and so on. 
Example Like I have date from which I have to compare is Like 31-12-2013 now from here next continues dates like 01-01-2014,02-01-2014,03-01-2014 only, No matter next records like i have dates in that table 05-01-2014,06-01-2014,07-01-2014. I just want first continuous dates.Hope this clear more what I want.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know thats what he said ( sort of ) but I dont think thats what he ment, well I assume not.

Comment: @RiggsFolly We'll see what the OP says. The question is a tad vague.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Aint this such fun!

Comment: Can you be more concretely in your question? Suppose, you have have `4, 100, 09-01-2014` cortege in your table, what would be the desired result?

Comment: Thanks for help guys but my question if little different, suppose i have date like 01-01-2014 , now from this date on-words I have to compare continuous dates from above table. Not using limit 3 or any because I have no idea how many records are there.

Comment: Example Like I have date from which I have to compare is Like 31-12-2013 now from here next continues dates like 01-01-2014,02-01-2014,03-01-2014 only, No matter next records like  i have dates in that table  05-01-2014,06-01-2014,07-01-2014. I just want first continuous dates.Hope this clear more what I want.

Comment: Put all this extra info into your original question, not as comments

Comment: @user3250071 Did you see my answer?

Comment: Thanks everyone for help. This is simpler even I'm thinking it. I just select last date from absent_report table and next present date like 1   101 01-01-2014
2   101 02-01-2014
3   101 03-01-2014 last date is 03-01-2014 and next present date and then compare these two dates. This will worked on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if either the next row has the following day or the previous row has the previous day. To do this, I used `DATE_ADD()` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810516/mysql-how-to-add-one-day-to-datetime-field-in-query). However, I am not sure if this would be better than implementing the logic in PHP alltogether.

```
SELECT sno, code, date FROM table AS current
WHERE
    DATE(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) = (SELECT date FROM table AS previous WHERE previous.date < current.date ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)
OR
    DATE(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL +1 DAY)) = (SELECT date FROM table AS next WHERE next.date > current.date ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY date ASC
```

See it work [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89bac08/1).

Comment: Solved.Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `BETWEEN` syntax

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-03';
```

Comment: `date` is not a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok thanks, I have removed all traces of my ignorance.

Comment: It's not ignorance, you weren't aware. You would be surprised as to how many people didn't know that `keys` is also a reserved word. A 25k member didn't know that. One can't be expected to know them all by heart. So when in doubt, check the MySQL.com website ;-) Then there's `SPATIAL` lol now there's a weird one.

Comment: I think what you are saying to me in a very polite ways is RTFM. Right?

Comment: Not at all Riggs. I have to visit that page too sometimes (to be 100% sure). Here's another weird one `ZEROFILL`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am not trying to be a smarty pants, but if you look at the bottom of that page you linked to you will see why I thought it was a reserved word, because it is. They have just put a frig into mysql to allow its use as an unquoted identifier.

Comment: It's an honest mistake. However, this is most likely to be a (pre-conceived) notion that's been passed-on over the years, probably pre-3.23 versions contained `date` as being a reserved word.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Almost definitely, well now you know I am no spring chicken! Is that social engineering :-) Of course I could have got the notion from some other database, I have used quite a few over the years.

Comment: I started out with dBase IV lol but we didn't need to worry about those (reserved words etc.), I wasn't a "programmer/coder" back then. Here's a tidbit I wasn't aware of till last week. In MySQL both `VALUES` and `VALUE` are valid, as opposed to Oracle where `VALUES` must be used exclusively; go figure.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I started on DMS a big-iron database that ran on UNIVAC with COBOL. Pre relational. Ahhh the good old days.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No I am not quite that old `1100-64` about half the power of my PC and filled a large room.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh yes, One in each of the System Support Processors.

Comment: I never "worked" with those *per se*, but I did see them *way back when*. I worked for a graphics house that used an APPLE IIe with a graphic design station to digitize logos. The bootup floppy cost **$90** if it ever screwed up (this was 28+ years ago now $$$). Guess what, the "boss" himself put his fingerprints on the exposed area, had to wait 2 weeks for a new copy; good one. lol looked good on him. (The APPLE IIe was considered "state of the art" back then lol